# Call sp_send_dbmail with multiple attachments in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The value of `@filenames` and `C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg` are the same.

`C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg` - this is working.
`@filenames` gives:

> file invalid

Why am I getting invalid file when I put it in a variable?

```
DECLARE @filenames varchar(max)
SET @filenames =  ''''
    +  STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + 'C:\' + [Filename]                                          
        FROM  TestTable
        WHERE Id = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')), 
    1, 1, '') +  ''''

EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Profile',
    @recipients = 'email@test.com',
    @subject = 'test shared',
    @body_format = 'TEXT',
    @body = 'test shared',
    @file_attachments =  @filenames
    -- 'C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg'
```

Comment: Did you check the docs? Probably because it only accepts a literal

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to drop the two `''''` strings from the concatenation. Instead of passing `'C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg'` (where the quotes are not a part of the value), you are passing `'''C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg'''` (which includes a leading and trailing quote in the value).

Try:

```
DECLARE @filenames varchar(max)
SET @filenames =  STUFF((
        SELECT ';' + 'C:\' + [Filename]
        FROM  TestTable
        WHERE Id = 1
        FOR XML PATH('')),
    1, 1, '')

EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Profile',
    @recipients = 'email@test.com',
    @subject = 'test shared',
    @body_format = 'TEXT',
    @body = 'test shared',
    @file_attachments =  @filenames
    -- 'C:\test1.jpg;C:\test2.jpg'
```

A better form of the `FOR XML` string concatenation technique is to replace `(SELECT ... FOR XML PATH(''))` with `(SELECT ... FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')`. This avoids problems with escaped XML characters like getting `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Even better, check out the relatively new `STRING_AGG()` function.  If order matters, the `WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY xxx)` option can be used.

**ADDENDUM**

If you have file names containing spaces or special characters that require that you quote the file paths, you would need to add these quotes to the innermost select inside the FOR XML concatenation.

```
        SELECT ';"C:\' + Filename + '"'
```

or

```
        STRING_AGG('"C:\' + Filename + '"', ';')
```

You should also take precautions to ensure that your filename values and do not open up a *path manipulation* security vulnerability with values like `'..\..\some-path\sensitive-data.txt'`.